# How to connect to mongoDB from typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb

I am getting an error when trying to add the mongo connection to the request

> Property 'dbClient' does not exist on type 'Request<ParamsDictionary>'.

I would like to have the connection available without having to add it to all my routes.

Thanks for your help

Here is my code snippet

```
const mongoUri = process.env.MONGO_URI ? process.env.MONGO_URI : "";
const mongoClient = new MongoClient(mongoUri);
async function createMongoConnecion() {
  try {
    await mongoClient.connect();
    console.log("connected");
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("Error connecting to mongo: " + err);
  } finally {
    console.log("Connected to mongo successfully!");
  }
}

app.use(async function (req, res, next) {
  req.dbClient = mongoClient;
  next();
});

routes.push(new SearchRoutes(app));
```

Comment: Try setting a breakpoint on `req.dbClient`. The error is telling you there is no property `dbClient` on the `req`. Check out what `req` is. `dbClient` is either in a different location or doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks .. but I trying to add it to the request and dbClient  is not a string

Answer (score 0):

### Step 1:

In the root folder create `types/express/index.d.ts` file with this content:

```js
declare global {
  namespace Express {
    interface Request {
      dbClient: object;
    }
  }
}
```

### Step 2

Update `tsconfig.json` file:

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "typeRoots": ["./types"]
  }
}
```

Comment: Same error.
I can pass it with req.body.dbClient =mongoClient. So not sure of the issue

Comment: Can you try it again? I updated my answer. I think the `global` was missing.